# VSCode C++ Initializer List Formatting

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, formatting

I'm using VSCode and the C++ formatting on each save. The formatting is generally great but the one annoying thing that comes up is the formatting of my initializer lists. If possible I'd prefer if it just doesn't bother formatting them or something because it changes stuff like this:

```
vertito this.ces.insert(vertices.end(), {
    // Front Face
    pos.x, pos.y, pos.z,
    pos.x + 1, pos.y, pos.z,
    pos.x, pos.y + 1, pos.z,
    pos.x + 1, pos.y + 1, pos.z,

  });
```

To this:

```
vertices.insert(vertices.end(), {
                                      // Front Face
                                      pos.x,
                                      pos.y,
                                      pos.z,
                                      pos.x + 1,
                                      pos.y,
                                      pos.z,
                                      pos.x,
                                      pos.y + 1,
                                      pos.z,
                                      pos.x + 1,
                                      pos.y + 1,
                                      pos.z,

                                  });
```

Any help is appreciated thank you!